# Can not use Elixir in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, elixir

### Question Summary

I'm trying to use Elixir in jupyter notebook but IElixir doesn't work.
  Does somebody know how to solve below error & use Elixir in jupyter notebook?

### Environments

- OS  Ubuntu ver.“18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)”
- CPU Intel Core i7-7700HQ 2.80GHz
- RAM 16GB
- GPU NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1600 Mobile

### Version Information

- anaconda 4.7.12
- jupyter 1.0.0
- elixir 1.9.4

### What I did & stacking points

I refer to IElixir github comments to built a deverop environment.
https://github.com/pprzetacznik/IElixir

- Progressed Situation
    Repository clone (done)
    `git clone https://github.com/pprzetacznik/IElixir.git`
    `cd IElixir`
    Built IElixir (Stacking Point)
    `mix deps.get`
    `mix test`
    `MIX_ENV=prod mix compile`
- Error was happen in `mix test`

  > kojiro@Inspiron7577:~/IElixir$ mix test
  >   ===> Compiling esqlite
  >   ===> Compiling /home/kojiro/IElixir/deps/esqlite/c_src/esqlite3_nif.c
  >   ===> /home/kojiro/IElixir/deps/esqlite/c_src/esqlite3_nif.c:25:10: fatal error: sqlite3.h: ãã®ãããªãã¡ã¤ã«ã ãã£ã¬ã¯ããªã¯ããã¾ãã #include “sqlite3.h” ^~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.
  >
  > ** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :esqlite, “/home/kojiro/.mix/rebar3 bare compile --paths=”/home/kojiro/IElixir/_build/test/lib/*/ebin"" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with “mix deps.compile esqlite”, update it with “mix deps.update esqlite” or clean it with “mix deps.clean esqlite”

first time, I thought error caused by esqlite could not compile in Mix.
so I tried all of error commented command but error doesn't solved.

- What I did to solve this error
  I follow to IElixir github comment.
  use `mix local.rebar --force`
  add `~/.mix/` to PATH then try mix test again.
  `(base) kojiro@Inspiron7577:~/IElixir$ export PATH="$PATH:~/.mix/"`
  but error doensn't solved.

I already tried to search "Could not compile dependency :esqlite" but all environmentl situation is different.
Does someone know how to solve this situation?

Comment: `esqlite` is a nif library, witch means is a library written in C. Make sure that you have gcc installed and it is added to the path.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this problem, however I found some resources that might help you get Elixir working in jupyter (if ever you didn't already found them !) :

This [medium post](https://medium.com/@tonyhammond/jupyter-notebooks-with-elixir-and-rdf-598689c2dad3) take you step by step through the installation, and also mention that is a Docker image that exists for it.

you can also find an installation tutorial with Docker [here](https://mattvonrocketstein.github.io/heredoc/ielixir-notebook-in-docker.html) (different from the above mentioned one)

Hope it helps.